# Bug while trying to approve a peer edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, review

Got a screenshot:

[image]

**I think** the problem is that the origin of the problem was that a the question, while I was trying to approve was already edited by a 2000+ rep user.

[image]

If that was the case the I would suggest a more appropriate error message and, regardless of this, the positioning of the error box should be fixed.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If it helps, I am using Chrome, latest versions, on a Mac 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pushed out some fixes - better error handling was among them.

Thanks for reporting!